# How do I import aws_network_interface_sg_attachment?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I can't seem to find it in [their documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_sg_attachment).

I'm trying to swap the state so that instead of letting it "default" using `aws_instance.vpc_security_ids` I have it explicitly set.

It may not be possible from what I can tell as they don't have an importer in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/ec2/vpc_network_interface_sg_attachment.go

I created a https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/27076 since it appears to be an issue with the provider itself.

Comment: It doesn't appear to support an import. If you just define the resource, with the correct ENI and SG, what does the `terraform plan` output look like?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary, like it's a new resource but fails on apply because it already exists.

Comment: It's very unclear what problem you are trying to solve by doing it this way, instead of explicitly setting it on the `aws_instance.vpc_security_group_ids` parameter.

Comment: when you attach to security_group_ids and you decide to change the properties of the security group the provider fails because it cannot remove the security group, because it's associated with a ENI but there's no delete of the association.

Comment: That's a long-standing bug/issue with AWS security groups in Terraform that still has open, unresolved tickets. I couldn't find any info on importing `aws_network_interface_sg_attachment`, not even an open ticket, so you may want to submit one.